# Gcard "fullpage" picture

Tags: graphics, cards

I am useing the gcard package in LaTeX. By default the package creates 4 "minipages" such that, when the a4 paper is folded twice - you end up with a neat invitation/folder.

I would like to add a picture, that fills up an entire "minipage", but I can not get it to look proper. Here is MVE:

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{gcard}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontcover}
\includegraphics[width = 10.3cm, height = 14cm]{fs_pic}

\end{frontcover}

\begin{insideright}
\includegraphics[width = 10.3cm, height = 14cm]{fs_pic}

\end{insideright}

\begin{insideleft}

Some text

\end{insideleft}

\begin{backcover}
Some more text

\end{backcover}
\end{document}
```

Which looks like:

[image: MWE rendering]

Ideally I would like to make the edges meet at the center of paper. However making the width of the picture larger, extends the picture over the paper edge - instead of pushing it towards the center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better lie!

The following tells LaTeX that the box containing the image is `0pt` in width, but then puts an image with width `.5\paperwidth` inside. This corrects the centring and prevents complaints about overfull boxes. (It should therefore only be used when you are sure you do not want to hear TeX's warnings!)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{gcard}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontcover}
  \centering
  \makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[width = .5\paperwidth, height = 14cm]{enfys}}
\end{frontcover}

\begin{insideright}
  \centering
  \makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[width = .5\paperwidth, height = 14cm]{enfys}}
\end{insideright}

\begin{insideleft}

Some text

\end{insideleft}

\begin{backcover}
Some more text

\end{backcover}
\end{document}
```

[image: effect of lying]

Comment: Better lie? I an missing something

Comment: @Repmat I told LaTeX that the box was `0pt` in width when it is actually `.5\paperwidth`. It makes the centring work. It was also a kind of joke, although one which very few people would be expected to understand. (On this site, most likely only me ;).)

Comment: @Repmat I've added a bit of explanation to my answer.